# How to split data frames with random subseting from single data frame in r?

Tags: r

I have a data frame in r with 1000 rows, I want to split this to 10 data frames each having 100 rows with sampling replace as False so that I get all 1000 rows, how to do that in loop and store all 10 data frames as list or any effective way to use one by one based on index?

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv")
nrow(data)
1000
```

I am splitting as

```
split1 <- sample_n(100, replace = FALSE)
```

similarly I need 10 splits with all the 1000 rows, sample_n gives me random 100 rows, I want to make sure 2nd split don't take any of the rows in split1, then I think I can store as a list or any effective way to use based on index

```
l = list(split1, split2,....)
```

No need to store in disk, just a intermediate R data, if this happens in loop for make code simple would be better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sample` to shuffle rows and `split` then by creating a group to split using `gl`

```
split(data[sample(seq_len(nrow(data))), ], gl(nrow(data)/100, 100))
```

This will give you list of 10 dataframes which would have 100 rows each with no rows repeated.

---

Using this on `mtcars` to create 4 groups of 8 rows each

```
split(mtcars[sample(seq_len(nrow(mtcars))), ], gl(nrow(mtcars)/8, 8))

#$`1`
#                  mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#AMC Javelin      15.2   8  304 150 3.15 3.44 17.3  0  0    3    2
#Merc 450SLC      15.2   8  276 180 3.07 3.78 18.0  0  0    3    3
#Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8  400 175 3.08 3.85 17.1  0  0    3    2
#Mazda RX4 Wag    21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
#Toyota Corona    21.5   4  120  97 3.70 2.46 20.0  1  0    3    1
#Merc 280         19.2   6  168 123 3.92 3.44 18.3  1  0    4    4
#Dodge Challenger 15.5   8  318 150 2.76 3.52 16.9  0  0    3    2
#Maserati Bora    15.0   8  301 335 3.54 3.57 14.6  0  1    5    8

#$`2`
#                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Duster 360         14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.57 15.8  0  0    3    4
#Honda Civic        30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.61 18.5  1  1    4    2
#Datsun 710         22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.32 18.6  1  1    4    1
#Fiat 128           32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.20 19.5  1  1    4    1
#Valiant            18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.46 20.2  1  0    3    1
#Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.25 18.0  0  0    3    4
#Lotus Europa       30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.51 16.9  1  1    5    2
#Ford Pantera L     15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.17 14.5  0  1    5    4
#.....
```

Comment: Works well, Thank You

Answer (score 1):

We can create a grouping variable with `%/%`

```
n <- 100
grp <- (seq_len(nrow(data))-1) %/%n  + 1
split(data[sample(nrow(data)),], grp)
```

---

using `mtcars` as an example

```
f1 <- function(data, n) {
   grp <- (seq_len(nrow(data))-1) %/%n + 1
   split(data[sample(nrow(data)),], grp)
 }

f1(mtcars, 8)
```